# Is there a workaround to submitting an slurm job that uses repository files and then switching git branches while waiting for it to finish?

Tags: git, slurm

I am often submitting slurm jobs that may sit in a queue for a period of time. The slurm script will reference code in my working directory, like a python training script.

While waiting, I would like to switch between different branches of my local repo. However, the issue with doing this is that when the slurm job finally starts, it will read code from whichever branch I am currently in.

My initial thought is that I could have the slurm script read from some temporary directory where a version of the repo is cloned, but I believe this may add extra complexity.
Are there any workarounds to this?

General workflow

```
git checkout dev1
sbatch run_training.sbatch
```

run_training.sbatch:

```
#SBATCH  args
...
python run_training.py
```

```
git checkout dev2
```

When the job starts, it will read the `run_training.py` in that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My initial thought is that I could have the slurm script read from some temporary directory where a version of the repo is cloned, but I believe this may add extra complexity. Are there any workarounds to this?

There are other workarounds based on variations of the idea you had. For example, you don't necessarily need point it to an entire separate clone of the repo. You could just clone the subset of the repo that it needs to run with.

If you want something simple, what I'd recommend is to just use [git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), which allows to create multiple working trees each checking out different branches of a single local repository.